# Remove key-mapping from org-mode

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, evil, keymap

I'm transitioning from VIM (using `GNU Emacs 24.5.1`). I want to move between "windows" using familiar keys i.e.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-k") 'windmove-up)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-j") 'windmove-down)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-h") 'windmove-left)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-l") 'windmove-right)
```

However in org-mode...

> C-k runs the command org-kill-line, which is an interactive Lisp
>   function in `org.el'.
>
> It is bound to C-k.
>
> (org-kill-line &optional ARG)
>
> Kill line, to tags or end of line.

So I tried removing the `org-kill-line` mapping but I couldn't get it to work:

```
(eval-after-load "org"
   '(define-key org-mode-map [remap org-kill-line] nil))
```

Disclaimer: I've only been using emacs for 3 days so far.

Comment: Consider using the "sharp quote" (#') instead of just "quote" (') when [quoting functions](http://endlessparentheses.com/get-in-the-habit-of-using-sharp-quote.html) (including commands, which are just interactive functions).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Org-mode is built-in to Emacs 24.5.1, so there's no need to `eval-after-load`. `with-eval-after-load` is also [preferred over](http://www.lunaryorn.com/2013/06/25/introducing-with-eval-after-load.html) `eval-after-load`.

Instead of trying to remap `org-kill-line`, why not just specify <kbd>C-k</kbd>?

```
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-k") nil)
```

Also, there may be other modes that bind a common key like <kbd>C-k</kbd>. Instead, you can use <kbd>C-c k</kbd>. The <kbd>C-(letter)</kbd> keys, by convention, are [reserved for user-specified bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1758639/864684).

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks @tianxiang-xiong

Comment: I believe this answer is partially incorrect.  While org-mode is distributed with Emacs, it is not loaded by default, so you do need `with-eval-after-load` to avoid potentially referencing `org-mode-map` before it is defined.  However, unbinding `C-k` is correct.